# If $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ where $x$ and $y$ ar not equal, what can we say about the result?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> If $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ where $x$ and $y$ ar not equal, what can we say about the result?

Can anyone explain how to go about this? Do we have to answer in terms of whether the function is differentiable and/or continuous? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: With things like this, you just plug in some random values and see what happens. What if $y=0$, for example?

Comment: If such a function is and continous, letting $y=x+\epsilon$ gives that $f'(x)=f(x)$, which implies that the function is exponwntial, but only the zero multiple of the exponwntial fufils this equation, so $f=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is supposed to be continuous, then for all $x \in \mathbb R$:$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{y \to x} f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\lim\limits_{y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f^\prime(x)$$ so $f$ is differentiable and satisfies the differential equation $y^\prime=y$. Hence $f(x)=\lambda e^x$.

*Is $f$ necessarily continuous... That is the question.*

Using the comments from [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) and [Ivan Neretin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269518/ivan-neretin), $e^x$ cannot be solution. **So if a solution exists, it cannot be continuous on $\mathbb R$.**

Comment: With $x=2$ and $y=0$ that solution seems to suggest $\lambda e = \dfrac{\lambda e^2-\lambda}{2}$, which is not the case

Comment: Which means we don't have a (non-trivial) differentiable solution.

Comment: Minor detail: There is a continuous solution on $\mathbb{R}$, namely $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: That's why I said "non-trivial".

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=x+2k$. Then we may rewrite the equation for $f$ as
$$
\tag{1}
f(x+2k)=2kf(x+k)+f(x).
$$
Suppose $f(x_0)=a$ and $f(x_0+1)=b$, where $x_0$ is an arbitrary real number. Then we get from $(1)$ with $k=1$:
$$
f(x_0+2)=2f(x_0+1)+f(x_0)=2b+a,\quad f(x_0+3)=2f(x_0+2)+f(x_0+1)=5b+2a.
$$
On the other hand we have $f(x_0+1/2)=f(x_0+1)-f(x_0)=b-a$. Using now $(1)$ with $k=1/2$ gives:
$$
\begin{align}
&f(x_0+3/2)=f(x_0+1)+f(x_0+1/2)=2b-a,\cr 
&f(x_0+2)=f(x_0+3/2)+f(x_0+1)=3b-a,\cr
&f(x_0+5/2)=f(x_0+2)+f(x_0+3/2)=5b-2a,\cr
&f(x_0+3)=f(x_0+5/2)+f(x_0+2)=8b-3a.\cr
\end{align}
$$
The values for $f(x_0+2)$ and $f(x_0+3)$ are the same only if $2b+a=3b-a$ and $5b+2a=8b-3a$, that is if $a=b=0$. But $x_0$ was arbitrary, so we may conclude that $f(x)=0$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace y by x + a (*y = x + a*) then this equation can be easier to solve. You will get *f(y) = f(x + a)*. Also if you change the counter by the following: *f(x + a)* = *f(x) + f '(x) a + 0.5  f ''(x)(a)<sup>2</sup>*, then it might become more clear.

Comment: That's if f(x) is differentiable, which it is not, as we already found.